# Got error 127 when reading table and Table is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

Getting Error ***`Table is marked as crashed and should be repaired`***
Table is using `MyIsam` engine.

```
130429  3:11:27 [Warning] IP address '221.174.22.58' could not be resolved: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. 
130429  4:41:10 [Warning] IP address '61.164.161.158' has been resolved to the host name '158.161.164.61.dial.wz.zj.dynamic.163data.com.cn', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
130429  4:49:00 [Warning] IP address '122.224.186.174' could not be resolved: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. 
130429  8:07:43 [Note] Hostname 'ip199.hichina.com' does not resolve to '121.199.26.215'.
130429  8:07:43 [Note] Hostname 'ip199.hichina.com' has the following IP addresses:
130429  8:07:43 [Note]  - 121.199.254.224

130429 10:23:41 [Note] Hostname 'ABTS-KK-dynamic-169.186.172.122.airtelbroadband.in' does not resolve to '122.172.186.169'.
130429 10:23:41 [Note] Hostname 'ABTS-KK-dynamic-169.186.172.122.airtelbroadband.in' has the following IP addresses:
130429 10:23:41 [Note]  - 92.242.132.27

130429 11:02:31 [Note] Hostname 'ABTS-KK-Static-100.2.166.122.airtelbroadband.in' does not resolve to '122.166.2.100'.
130429 11:02:31 [Note] Hostname 'ABTS-KK-Static-100.2.166.122.airtelbroadband.in' has the following IP addresses:
130429 11:02:31 [Note]  - 92.242.132.27

130429 13:07:01 [ERROR] Got error 127 when reading table '.\tr_rgc\ref_can'
130429 13:07:55 [Warning] IP address '27.7.48.173' could not be resolved: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. 
130429 13:11:58 [Note] Hostname 'ABTS-KK-static-213.102.166.122.airtelbroadband.in' does not resolve to '122.166.102.213'.
130429 13:11:58 [Note] Hostname 'ABTS-KK-static-213.102.166.122.airtelbroadband.in' has the following IP addresses:
130429 13:11:58 [Note]  - 92.242.132.27

130429 13:11:58 [ERROR] Got error 127 when reading table '.\tr_rgc\ref_can'
130429 13:26:59 [ERROR] Got an error from thread_id=732, ..\..\..\mysql-5.5.30\storage\myisam\ha_myisam.cc:912
130429 13:26:59 [ERROR] MySQL thread id 732, OS thread handle 0x5e4, query id 93434 122.166.102.213 TR_RGC Checking table
check table ref_can
130429 13:27:26 [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: ![Table '.\tr_rgc\ref_can' is marked as crashed and should be repaired][1]
130429 13:27:36 [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Table '.\tr_rgc\ref_can' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130429 13:27:52 [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Table '.\tr_rgc\ref_can' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130429 13:28:18 [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Table '.\tr_rgc\ref_can' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
130429 13:28:22 [ERROR] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Table '.\tr_rgc\ref_can' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

I did `Check Table` also but getting error, refer [snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtxMp.jpg). **Before marking duplicate, please review the [snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtxMp.jpg).**

Comment: So... What does `REPAIR TABLE ref_can;` do?

Comment: Checking with `REPAIR TABLE ref_can;`

Comment: Its not working, please review the Snap.

Comment: I see no `REPAIR TABLE` output in any link you provided.... But assuming you actually tried it: then you're probably in big trouble. [according to this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html), you can try a `myisamchk --safe-recover` from the command line, but it may be your data has been to damaged to recover.

Comment: From myslq console use this:
mysql>REPAIR TABLE <database>.<tablename>